# SurfaceControllers in Umbraco 7.5.6

Tags: controller, umbraco

I'm brand new to Umbraco (I've just set it up today) and I am trying to create a surface controller. I've read a lot of documentation, saying it should be placed in a folder called App_code - but it's not there!
Do I have to create the folder myself, or is surface controllers placed somewhere else in the newer versions of Umbraco?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much experienced with .NET and C# you are. Keeping the logic in *App_Code* folder is not a best practice, but it allows code to be compiled "on the fly" and don't require Visual Studio project and compilation of library / DLL.

Usually, controllers lives in different areas, depending of the application architecture, but they are then compiled and included inside the artifact(s) referenced inside the web application which Umbraco is.

If you're not experienced and don't want / need to have a VS solution - create *App_Code* directory manually and place .cs class of the controller there. It should work :)